# Is IdentityServer3 WindowsAuthentication post logout redirect possible?

Tags: windows-authentication, identityserver3

I was wondering if it is possible to add a redirect Url to the post-logout action when using the Windows Authentication module of IdentityServer3? Currently, it seems to leave users on a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the WindowsAuthentication module, then you don't want to redirect to that STS for signout (since it's all about integrated windows auth, and the only sighout is logging out of the windows machine). I'd suggest to suppress the redirect for signout to the WindowsAuthentication STS in the WS-Fed Katana middleware you're using in IdentityServer. Handle the `RedirectingToIdentityProvder` (or whatever the event is called) and call the API to suppress the redirect.